# wso2 identity server: automate the deploy of policies, claims, and other configs

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have hundreds of different identity server configurations (policies, claims, service provider, etc)

And i need to repeat the same configuration on several environments: dev, test, prod

To do it by hands through export import in web console - it's a nightmare.

What is the best practice to do an automatic configuration deployment to wso2is?

I'm thinking about the following options:

- create a script that will call admin services to import identity server configs
- create custom deployer (like a synapse & dataservice deployers, etc) and call admin services or do in-memory api calls
- find where and how it's stored in database and do sql script to fill database

Maybe there is something exists for config deployment and I can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own scripts or custom methods to manage the deployments. But you have to maintain those scripts by your self.

In that case, you can use deployment automation tools such as Puppet, Chef and etc..

You can use [WSO2 Puppet modules](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2016/03/tutorial-how-to-use-wso2-puppet-modules-to-deploy-wso2-products/) to deploy your configuration in different environments.

Answer (score 0):

just in case if somebody need the file-based deployer

created a groovy script deployer that could be used for different purposes.

- [service-provider deployer](https://github.com/eleks/com.eleks.carbon.commons/tree/master/deployers/wso2is/service-provider)
- [policy deployer](https://github.com/eleks/com.eleks.carbon.commons/tree/master/deployers/wso2is/policy)